# SQL - How to calculate opening and closing balance

Tags: sql

I'm trying to figure out a way to calculate two new columns for the following model:

[image: enter image descriptiion here]

Link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/0a6ce9/1

**A) first column:**  should be the "OPENING_BALANCE". It needs to be the sum of the "AMOUNT" column starting off when transaction date started. The transaction date could be any.

**B) Second column:** Should be the "CLOSING_BALANCE". This one will always be the sum of the "opening balance" from previous day + "amount" of the current day. So, by the second TRANSACTION_DATE forward, the "opening balance" will always be the "closing balance" from the previous day.

Here's an example:
[image]

Can anyone share any examples of how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUM()` window function and a `CASE` expression to check for the 1st transaction:

```
SELECT *,
       CASE 
         WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TRANSACTION_DATE, TRANSACTION_ID) = 1 THEN AMOUNT
         ELSE SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (ORDER BY TRANSACTION_DATE, TRANSACTION_ID) - AMOUNT 
       END OPENING_BALANCE,
       SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (ORDER BY TRANSACTION_DATE, TRANSACTION_ID) CLOSING_BALANCE
FROM TRANSATION_TABLE;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=803f20c39f58a6ca778a69499ad5be11).

Comment: Hi, this works very nice when the ID is on the select. But if we aggregate by TRANSACTION_DATE, it behaves weird.
Link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c820866a7e89318f1aa4c2229b9cce6f

Comment: @Renato why would you do that? My query returns exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi @forpas, thanks for the reply. The query needs to be able to be grouped by a variety of columns, which might not always be the ID. I added another ID in the example (link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=dfe789514f70c37e88dcde8d5aebd2af ) and tried a group by transaction date and this other ID, the same error happens. It's like it can't really sum the first opening balance

Comment: @Renato my answer is about the question as you posted it. If you have a new requirement you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select f.TRANSACTION_ID, f.TRANSACTION_DATE, f.AMOUNT,CASE WHEN sum(s.AMOUNT)-f.AMOUNT >0
   THEN sum(s.AMOUNT)-f.AMOUNT ELSE s.AMOUNT END AS OPENING_BALANCE,sum(s.AMOUNT) as CLOSING_BALANCE
from TRANSATION_TABLE f inner join TRANSATION_TABLE s on f.TRANSACTION_ID >= s.TRANSACTION_ID
   group by f.amount order by f.TRANSACTION_ID asc
```